# SDN doesn't work if I activate `-parameters` compiler's argument

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

I use Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE and experience the following exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing; Description: Expected a parameter named 0
```

in the following place:

```
@Query("" +
        "MATCH (u:User)-[:LOCATION]-(l:Location)-[r]-(p:PostalCode) " +
        "WHERE id(u)={0} " +
        "RETURN l, r, p"
)
Location findUserLocation(long userId);
```

in case if I use `-parameters` argument for my java compiler.

Do anyone know, why it may not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because compilation with `-parameters` allows the framework to get real parameter names from the source code.

In other words, it works the same way as : `findUserLocation(@Param("userId") long userId)`

Changing the query to use `{userId}` instead of `{0}` should work. If you need to be compatible with different compilation options, use `@Param` as stated above.